# Is it possible to have a pointer to a pointer point to the variable pointed by the first pointer?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, memory, dynamic

Would this work:

```
Class MyClass{

public:
    void Foo();

private:
    MyClass** ppMyClass;

};

MyClass* pMyClass = new MyClass;

ppMyClass = &pMyClass;

delete pMyClass;

ppMyClass-> Foo();
```

If it would not work, what would be the right way to assign a pointer to a pointer and use it too access functions to the class it points to? The thing is, I am wondering if the error there is caused by a memory leak: [Why do I get the WSAENOTSOCK error in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462669/why-do-wsaasyncselect-fails-in-this-code)

So, would that work?

Comment: No, `ppMyClass->Foo();` cannot work as `ppMyClass` is a `MyClass**` rather than a `MyClass*`.

Comment: Furthermore, `*ppMyClass` is a dangling pointer after the `delete`...

Comment: Anyone has an idea why the code in the link won't work then? At least, do you see a memory leak in the code in the link above?

Comment: memory link? many links. many

Comment: and seriously: memory leak (or even link) doesn't interrupt the linker to do its linking stuff. and no, there's no leak there

Answer (score 2):

No, `ppMyClass->Foo();` cannot work as `ppMyClass` is a `MyClass**` rather than a `MyClass*`.

You could theoretically do `(*ppMyClass)->Foo()`, although in your particular code snippet, that would be undefined behaviour as you `delete`d `pMyClass` immediately before.